# Find recent changes in confluence wiki

Tags: confluence

How do I view recently changed pages in a confluence space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On the `Dashboard` (*confluence-server-url*/dashboard.action) you will find an overview of the recently changed pages and blogposts
- You can display this list on any wiki page (if you have the appropriate permissions) by using the [Macro Browser](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Recently+Updated+Macro). Search and add the [Recently Updated Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Macros). You can customize what should be displayed.

> The Recently Updated Dashboard macro is similar to this macro, but is intended for display on the Confluence dashboard.